# Dependency Injection: Resolve in function

Tags: .net, dependency-injection

I am trying to use the StructureMap IOC container in one of my .NET applications.

I have a series of IMessageHandler implementation that perform some action based on a message received from a service. Each implementation could have a variety of dependencies.

Currently, I am creating a new instance of these handlers when a message is received.

```
public Task HandleMessage(QueueMessage message)
{
        if (!messageHandlerMap.ContainsKey(message.GetType()))
        {
            throw new Exception("No message handler was found for message type: " + message.GetType().ToString());
        }

        Type messageHandlerType = messageHandlerMap[message.GetType()];
        IMessageHandler messageHandler = (IMessageHandler)Activator.CreateInstance(messageHandlerType);
        return messageHandler.HandleMessage(message);
}
```

Since this occurs in a local method, how would I use StructureMap to provide these message handlers with their dependencies? Do I need to inject the container and have it create the message handlers?

Comment: Why do you need to create a new message handler for every message? Does the handler contain state?

Comment: I don't need to create a new handler, but I do need to have a mapping between the type of message and the messagehandler. Where do I initialize the message handlers?

Comment: Create the Handlers in the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/), and then inject a `Dictionary<Type,IMessageHandler>` into your class. Such dictionary will contain the already-built `IMessageHandler` instances.

Answer (score 0):

I did what Yacoub mentioned I should do in the comments above.

```
public class MessageHandlerResolver : IMessageHandlerResolver
{
    private IEnumerable<IMessageHandler> handlers;
    public MessageHandlerResolver(IEnumerable<IMessageHandler> handlers)
    {
        this.handlers = handlers;
    }

    public IMessageHandler Resolve(Type type)
    {
        IMessageHandler handler = handlers.FirstOrDefault(h => h.MessageType == type);
        if(handler == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("No handler found for message type " + type.ToString(), "type");
        }
        return handler;
    }
}
```

You can then configure your Message Handlers in the IOC container and use list injection to inject them here